# AngularJS isolated scope with parent values set through ajax

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a reusable directive for a form.
Everything was working well when I used

```
scope: "="
```

in my directive options.

However I'm trying to pass a callback function from an attribute to my http factory and for that I need to set callback: "&".

Therefore I've changed 'scope' to:

```
scope: {
formData: "=ngModal", callback: "&onSuccess"
}
```

However this doesn't work. The form is processed correctly (it shows in my HTML) but when I try to enter a value in the input fields I get the following error in my console:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
```

This is my directive code:

```
tpFormModule.directive('tpForm', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'modules/tpForm/tpForm.tpl.html',
        scope: {
            formData: "=ngModel"
        }
    };
});
```

This is my template:

```
    <form name='tpForm' class='form col-md-9' novalidate ng-submit='processForm()'>

    <div class='form-group' ng-repeat='(index, item) in $parent.formData' ng-switch='item.type'>
        <label class='control-label'>{{item.label}}</label>

        <!-- TEXT -->

        <input ng-switch-when='TEXT' class='form-control' ng-model='$parent.formData[index]["value"]'>

        <!-- SELECT -->
        <select ng-switch-when='SELECT' class='form-control' ng-model='$parent.formData[index]["value"]' ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in item.possible_options">
        </select>

        <!-- TEXTAREA -->
        <textarea ng-switch-when='TEXTAREA' class='form-control'>
            {{item.formatted_value}}
        </textarea>

        <!-- FOREIGN OBJECT -->
        <span ng-switch-when='FOREIGN_OBJECT'>
          <p class="form-control-static">{{item.value}}</p>
          <input type='hidden' ng-model='$parent.formData[index]["value"]'>
          </span>

    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class='form-group'>
        <button class='btn btn-success'>Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

$parent.formData is set after the document has been loaded through an AJAX call. I think that this is where it goes wrong, but I don't understand how to update the isolated scope properties after the page load and after the $parent.formData has been updated through AJAX.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. The question is what?

Comment: Hate to ask but could you put up your code (or something very similar) on Plunker or JSFiddle? Particular interested in seeing how you've got everything wired up with the parent.

Comment: I've tried, but that doesn't work out of the box (which should though because I'm trying to create something reusable :P ) I've found something interesting on the web which I'm going to try out today => when I've solved this issue I will give you an update.

Answer (score 0):

After starting from scratch with the help of some other examples I managed to get it working.

Main trick was to set the controller within the directive:
Now all fields are added to the same scope as the form is in. So nothing to do with $parent etc.

```
tpForm.directive('tpFormDirective', function()
```

{
  return {
    controller: 'tpFormCtrl',
    templateUrl: "modules/tpForm/directives/form.tpl.html",
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      tpForm: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs)
    {
    }
  };
});

I work from within this plunker which you can use as reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/W1KxuL?p=preview